# Data collection framework

Tags: business-process-management, data-collection

Suppose you need to collect data from a bunch of people, and then collate their responses, is there a good framework to build an application to coordinate this activity? Are there any off-the-shelf products for this purpose?

A simple way of doing this would be to send an Excel sheet to everyone asking them to fill it up and manually combine what everyone gives back, but if we're doing this repeatedly, say weekly or monthly, it becomes a bit of a pain. Also, doing error checking and insulating against typos is also tough if the data being collected isn't too small..

-Pradyumna

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ETL (Extract, Translate, Load) tool for this. Pentaho ETL/Kettle and Talend are very good open source tools to do this.

http://kettle.pentaho.com/
http://www.industrial-tsi.com/

I think talend is the easiest to get started with.